# Terminal Calculator/Parser Inspired by gcalccmd

Tags: c, parsing, calculator

My program takes input from the user in two ways:

- By passing input as an argument whilst calling the command
- By taking any number of inputs after calling the command

The program is a terminal calculator that recognizes parentheses, operators, and errors as soon as you pass an expression. If you happen to come across an (non-internal) error, it will always return a suitable error message. Optionally, the user may pass a number alongside the expression to round the answer to a certain number of digits.

The program mainly centers around the manipulation of strings. As far as I know, there aren't any bugs or memory leaks. However, I've been coding for a few months, and I am in no way an expert. Because of my limited knowledge of C, I'm afraid the methods used in my program are unnecessarily complex. Constructive criticism of any kind is welcome.

> Note: I used the `goto` keyword many times, mostly as a way to organize error handling. I know that use of such is frowned upon in most cases, but I thought this would be a good implementation of it.

**main.c**

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "eval.h"

bool CMD_LINE; // Using command-line interface?

void print_help(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *expr = NULL, *swap = NULL;
    size_t bufsize = 999,   // Maximum input size
    ndec;                   // Number of decimal places
    double result;

    CMD_LINE = true;
    if (argc == 1) {
        CMD_LINE = false;
        goto interactive;
    }

    command_line:
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) { // Interpret help flag if present
        if (argc == 2)
            print_help();
        else
            fail("Incorrect flag usage");
    }
    if ((expr = simplify(argv[1], 0)) == NULL) {
        putchar('\n');
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (argc == 3) {    // Interpret decimal count if present
        if (strspn(argv[2], VAL_CHRS + 10) == strlen(argv[2]))  /* Decimal count contains only digits    */
            ndec = atoi(argv[2]);                               /* VAL_CHRS[11->20] = '1', ..., '9', '0' */
        else
            goto invdec_err;
        if (ndec > DBL_DIG)
            goto invdec_err;
    }
    #ifdef DEBUG
    puts("\n\e[4mresult\e[24m");
    #endif
    result = stod(expr);
    free(expr);
    puts(expr = dtos(result, argc == 3 ? ndec : 6));    // 6 = default number of decimals shown
    free(expr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    interactive:
    for (;;) {
        printf("> ");
        expr = calloc(bufsize + 1, sizeof(char));
        getline(&expr, &bufsize, stdin);
        if (!strcmp(expr, "\n")) {
            free(expr);
            break;
        }
        swap = expr;    // Swap causes 'still reachable' error in valgrind
        expr = simplify(expr, 0);
        free(swap);
        if (expr != NULL) {
            result = stod(expr);
            free(expr);
            puts(expr = dtos(result, 6));
            free(expr);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    invdec_err:
        fail("Invalid decimal count");
}

void print_help(void) {
    printf("Usage: %s [EXPRESSION] [ROUND]\n", PROG_NAME);
    puts("High-accuracy terminal calculator");
    puts("Encapsulation within apostrophes (') is recommended");
    puts("This software falls under the GNU Public License v3.0\n");

    puts("++, --     ++x, --x         Increment, decrement");
    puts("!, !!      !x, y!!x         Square root, other root        ↑ Higher precedence");
    puts("^          x^y              Exponent");
    puts("*, /, %    x*y, x/y, x%y    Multiply, divide, remainder    ↓ Lower Precedence");
    puts("+, -       x+y, x-y         Add, subtract\n");

    puts("           (x + y)          Control precedence");
    puts("           x(y)             Multiply terms\n");

    puts("GitHub repository: https://github.com/crypticcu/eval");
    puts("Report bugs to:    cryptic.cu@protonmail.com");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**eval.c**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "eval.h"

/* NOTES **********************************************************

 - Parameters contain a leading underscore
 - Variables shared between files are uppercase
 - Variables named "nchr" hold index positions
    o Cannot be negative, so use size_t
 - An "obstruction" is an invalid character found to be in between
   operator and operand
 - In terms of operation, a "limit" is the furthest right- or
   left-hand index position, relative to an operator in which an
   operation would take place
 - stod() is used as a replacement to atof()
    o Recognizes numbers that cannot computed accurately
    o Number of accurate digits determined by __DBL_DIG__ (DBL_DIG)
 - dtos() is used as a replacement to gcvt()
    o Returns dynamically-allocated string
    o Does not require buffer

 ******************************************************************/

void fail(const char *_desc) {
    printf("%s\n", _desc);
    if (CMD_LINE)   // Exit program if using command-line
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void printu(const char *_s, size_t _hpos) {
    for (int nchr = 0; nchr < strlen(_s); nchr++) {
        if (nchr == _hpos)
            printf("\e[4m");    // Underline
        putchar(_s[nchr]);
        if (nchr == _hpos)
            printf("\e[24m");   // Reset underline
    }
}

char *dtos(double _x, size_t _sig) {    // Dynamic memory: numstr
    size_t nwhole = nplaces(_x);

    if (nwhole > DBL_DIG)
        return STR_OVER;
    if (nwhole + _sig > DBL_DIG)
        _sig = DBL_DIG - nwhole;
    if (_sig > DBL_DIG) // Decimal place exceeds accurate number allotted by system
        _sig = DBL_DIG;

    bool is_negative = _x < 0, is_decimal = _sig, only_decimal = _x < 1 && _x > -1, only_whole = isequal(_x, (int) _x);
    size_t reqsize = nwhole + _sig + is_negative + is_decimal + only_decimal;
    char *numstr = (char *) calloc(reqsize + 1, sizeof(char));

    if (numstr == NULL) // Allocation fails
        return NULL;
    if (is_negative) {  // Negative and decimal requirements
        numstr[0] = '-';
        if (only_decimal) {
            numstr[1] = '0';
            numstr[2] = '.';
        }   
    } else if (only_decimal) {
        numstr[0] = '0';
        numstr[1] = '.';
    }
    for (int nchr = is_negative + only_decimal * 2, place = nplaces(_x) - !(nwhole == FLT_DIG && only_whole); nchr < reqsize; nchr++, place--) {    // Skip characters reserved for negative sign and decimal point, if present
        numstr[nchr] = getdigit(_x, place) + 48;    // '0' = 48
        if (place == 0) {
            if (only_whole)
                break;
            else if (nchr + 1 != reqsize)
                numstr[++nchr] = '.';
        }
    }
    return numstr;
}

char *popsub(const char *_s, size_t _low, size_t _high) { // Dynamic memory: sub
    char *sub;  // Substring to be 'popped' from string

    if (_low >= strlen(_s) || _high >= strlen(_s) || _low > _high ||    // Low/high indices exceed range of string || Low index is greater than high || Allocation fails
    (sub = (char *) calloc(_high - _low + 2, sizeof(char))) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (size_t nchr_old = _low, nchr_new = 0; nchr_old <= _high; nchr_old++, nchr_new++)
        sub[nchr_new] = _s[nchr_old];
    return sub;
}

char *pushsub(char *_s, char *_sub, size_t _low, size_t _high) {    // Dynamic memory: newstr
    char *newstr = (char *) calloc(
        strlen(_s)              // Original length
        - (_high - _low + 1)    // Take away number of characters being removed
        + strlen(_sub)          // Add size of substring
        + 1                     // Add space for null character
    , sizeof(char));
    int nchr_new;
    
    if (_low >= strlen(_s) || _high >= strlen(_s) || _low > _high || newstr == NULL) // Low/high indices exceed range of string || Low index is greater than high || Allocation fails
        return NULL;                                 
    for (nchr_new = 0; nchr_new < _low; nchr_new++)
        newstr[nchr_new] = _s[nchr_new];    // Add contents of old string up to point of integration
    for (int nchr_sub = 0; nchr_sub < strlen(_sub); nchr_sub++, nchr_new++)
        newstr[nchr_new] = _sub[nchr_sub];  // Integrate substring
    for (int nchr_old = _high + 1; nchr_old < strlen(_s); nchr_old++, nchr_new++)
        newstr[nchr_new] = _s[nchr_old];    // Add rest of old string
    free(_s);
    free(_sub);
    return newstr;
}

char *simplify(const char *_expr, size_t _from) {   // Dynamic memory: subA, subB, expr
    bool read_parenth = false;
    char chr, *subA = NULL, *subB = NULL,
        *expr = (char *) calloc(strlen(_expr) + 1, sizeof(char));   // Modifiable expression
    size_t par_low, par_high;
    int invpos;
    double result;

    if (expr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (!_from) {   // Check syntax and parenthesese only once (_from is always 0 on first call)
        if ((invpos = chk_syntax(_expr)) != CHK_PASS)   // Check for syntax errors
            goto syntax_err;
        if ((invpos = chk_parenth(_expr)) != CHK_PASS)  // Check for parenthetical errors
            goto syntax_err;
    }
    strcpy(expr, _expr); // Copy constant expression to modifiable one
    for (int nchr = _from; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {    // Go straight to evaluate() if '-p' is passed
        if (chr == ')') {
            par_high = nchr;
            read_parenth = false;
            if ((subA = popsub(expr, par_low, par_high)) == NULL)
                goto popsub_err;
            expr[par_low] = (toast(expr, par_low)) ? '*' : ' ';
            expr[par_high] = (toast(expr, par_high)) ? '*' : ' ';
            result = evaluate(subA);    // Value passed to result to increase efficiency and improve debugging mode clarity
            if (isequal(result, DBL_FAIL))  // evaluate() does not return heap address, so can be called without assignment
                goto evaluate_err;
            if ((subB = dtos(result, DBL_DIG)) == NULL)
                goto dtos_err;
            free(subA);
            if ((expr = pushsub(expr, subB, par_low + 1, par_high - 1)) == NULL)    // Do not overwite space where parentheses used to be
                goto pushsub_err;
            if (_from)
                return expr;
        }
        else if (chr == '(') {
            if (read_parenth) {
                subA = expr;    // Swap causes 'still reachable' error in valgrind
                if ((expr = simplify(expr, nchr)) == NULL)
                    goto simplify_err;
                free(subA);
            } else {
                read_parenth = true;
                par_low = nchr;
            }
        }
    }
    subA = expr;
    result = evaluate(expr);
    if (isequal(result, DBL_FAIL))
        goto evaluate_err;
    if ((expr = dtos(result, DBL_DIG)) == NULL)
        goto dtos_err;
    free(subA);
    return expr;

    syntax_err:
        printf("Syntax error: ");
        printu(_expr, invpos);
        free(expr);
        return NULL;
    evaluate_err:
        free(subA); // Failure message not required; would have already been handled by evaluate()
        return NULL;
    dtos_err:
        free(subA);
        fail("Internal error (simplify.dtos)"); // Exits program if using command-line
        return NULL;
    popsub_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Internal error (simplify.dtos)");
        return NULL;
    pushsub_err:
        fail("Internal error (simplify.pushsub)");
        return NULL;
    simplify_err:
        free(subA);
        fail("Internal error (simplify.simplify)");
        return NULL;
}

bool isequal(double _x, double _y) {
    return fabs(_x - _y) < FLT_EPSILON;
}

bool isin(const char _x, const char *_y) {
    for (int nchr = 0; nchr < strlen(_y); nchr++)
        if (_x == _y[nchr])
            return true;
    return false;
}

bool isnumer(char _c) {
    return (isdigit(_c) || _c == '-' || _c == '.');
}

bool toast(const char *_expr, size_t _parpos) { // To asterisk?
    char chr = _expr[_parpos],
         next,  // Character after parenthesis
         last;  // Character before parenthesis
    
    next =  _parpos < strlen(_expr) - 1 ? _expr[_parpos + 1] : 0;
    last = _parpos ? _expr[_parpos - 1] : 0;
    return (isdigit(last) && isnumer(next)  ||
        chr == '(' && last == ')'           ||
        chr == ')' && next == '(') ? true : false;
}

size_t getdigit(double _x, int _place) {
    size_t digit;

    _x = fabs(_x);
    if (abs(_place) > DBL_DIG || _x > LLONG_MAX)    // Place cannot be over/under place limit; Any 'x' over max llong causes overflow on conversion
        return 0;   // Digits that cannot be printed
    for (int nchr = 0; nchr <= abs(_place); _place > 0 ? (_x /= 10) : (_x *= 10), nchr++)
        digit = ((long long int) _x - (long long int) (_x / 10) * 10);
    return digit;
}

size_t nplaces(double _x) {
    _x = fabs(_x);  // log of negative is undefined
    if (_x == 0)    // log of zero is undefined
        return 1;
    return log(_x)/log(10) + 1;
}

int chk_parenth(const char *_expr) {
    char chr;
    int nopen = 0, nclosed = 0, nchr;

    for (nchr = 0; (chr = _expr[nchr]); nchr++) // Get number of closed parentheses
        if (chr == ')')
            nclosed++;
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = _expr[nchr]); nchr++) {
        if (chr == '(')
            nopen++;
        else if (chr == ')')
            nopen--;
        if (nopen > nclosed) {  // Extra open parenthesis?
            while ((chr = _expr[--nchr]) != '(');   // Find last instance of open parenthesis
            return nchr;
        }
        if (nopen < 0)  // Extra closed?
            return nchr;
    }
    return CHK_PASS;
}

int chk_syntax(const char *_expr) {
    char chr,
         lead = 0,  // Last non-space 
         trail = 0, // Next non-space
         last = 0,  // Immediate last
         next = 1;  // Immediate next
    size_t nsingle = 0, // Single operators
           ndouble = 0, // Double operators
           npoint = 0,  // Decimal points
           nchr_err;    // Index position of syntax error

    #ifdef DEBUG
    puts("\e[4mchk_syntax\e[24m");
    #endif
    for (size_t nchr = 0; (chr = _expr[nchr]); nchr++) {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("single: %ld\tdouble: %ld\tchr: %c\n", nsingle, ndouble, chr);
        #endif
        if (nchr)
            last = _expr[nchr - 1];
        if (nchr != strlen(_expr))
            next = _expr[nchr + 1];
        if (next != 0)
            for (int i = nchr + 1; _expr[i]; i++)
                if(!isspace(_expr[i])) {
                    trail = _expr[i];
                    break;
                }
        if (isdigit(chr) || chr == '(' || chr == ')')   // CHECK OPERATORS
            nsingle = 0, ndouble = 0;
        else if (isin(chr, DBLS) && (chr == last && isin(last, DBLS) || chr == next && isin(next, DBLS))) {
            if (chr != '!' && isdigit(lead) || chr == '!' && trail == '!' && !isdigit(lead) && lead != '.') // Operator is obstruction
                return nchr;    
            if (chr == '!' && lead == '!' && !isdigit(trail) && trail != '.') { // Operator isn't obstruction; find obstruction
                for (nchr_err = nchr; (chr = _expr[nchr_err]) != trail; nchr_err++);
                return nchr_err;
            }
            ndouble++;
        }
        else if (isin(chr, OPERS) && !(isin(chr, UNRY) && isin(lead, BNRY)))    // Extra conditionals needed to prevent 'x + !y' from being a syntax error
            nsingle++;  
        if (!isdigit(chr) && chr != '.') // CHECK DECIMAL POINTS
            npoint = 0;
        else if (chr == '.')
            npoint++;
        if (nsingle == 2 || ndouble == 3 || npoint == 2 ||  /* Extra operator or comma ||              */   //  CHECK ERRORS
            !isin(chr, VAL_CHRS) && !isspace(chr) ||        /* Is not a valid character nor a space || */
            isdigit(chr) && isdigit(lead) && lead != last)  /* Two numbers side-by-side w/o operator   */
            return nchr;
        if (!isspace(chr))
            lead = chr;
    }
    return CHK_PASS;
}

int getlim(char *_expr, size_t _operpos, char _dir) {
    bool reading = false, read_digit;
    char chr;
    int lim = -1, nchr;

    if (_dir != 'l' && _dir != 'r') // Left and right directions only
        return INT_FAIL;
    for (nchr = _dir == 'r' ? _operpos + 1 : _operpos - 1; (chr = _expr[nchr]) && nchr >= 0; _dir == 'r' ? nchr++ : nchr--) {
        if (isnumer(chr) && !reading)
            reading = true;
        else if (!isnumer(chr) && reading) {
            lim = _dir == 'r' ? nchr - 1 : nchr + 1;
            break;
        }
        if (isdigit(chr))
            read_digit = true;
    }
    if (!reading || !read_digit)    // No value found
        return INT_FAIL;
    else {
        if (nchr == -1) // Reached beginning of expression
            lim = 0;
        else if (chr == 0)  // Reached end of expression
            lim = strlen(_expr) - 1;
    }
    return lim;
}

size_t fobst(const char *_expr, size_t _operpos, size_t _llim, size_t _rlim) {
    bool l_obstr = false, r_obstr = false;
    char chr, oper = _expr[_operpos];
    int nchr = _operpos,
        off = 0;    // Offset from operator position

    if (_llim == INT_FAIL)  // Left limit of unary operation is operator position
        _llim = 0;
    if (_rlim == INT_FAIL)
        _rlim = strlen(_expr) - 1;
    if (_llim >= strlen(_expr) || _rlim >= strlen(_expr) || _llim > _rlim)
        return INT_FAIL;
    while (off < (int) strlen(_expr)) {
        if (nchr >= _llim && nchr <= _rlim) {
            chr = _expr[nchr];
            if (isin(chr, OPERS) && chr != oper && chr != '-')
                off < 0 ? (l_obstr = true) : (r_obstr = true);
        }
        off <= 0 ? (off = -(off - 1)) : (off = -off);
        nchr = _operpos + off;
    }
    if (l_obstr && r_obstr)
        return LEFT | RIGHT;
    else if (l_obstr && !r_obstr)
        return LEFT;
    else if (!l_obstr && r_obstr)
        return RIGHT;
    else
        return 0;
}

double evaluate(const char *_expr) {    // Dynamic memory: result_str, expr
    char chr,
        *result_str = NULL, // Operation result
        *expr = (char *) calloc(strlen(_expr) + 1, sizeof(char));   // Modifiable expression
    size_t llim, rlim;  // Left- and right-hand limits of operation
    int nchr;
    double result,  // Operation result;    Final return value
           lval, rval;  // Left and right values of operation

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n\e[4mevaluate\e[24m\n%s\n", _expr);
    #endif
    if (expr == NULL)
        return DBL_FAIL;
    strcpy(expr, _expr);    // Copy constant expression to modifiable one
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {
        if (isin(chr, OPERS))
            goto evaluate;
    }
    goto reevaluate;    // Skip main loop if no operators are found

    evaluate:
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {    // INCREMENT/DECREMENT
        if (chr == '+' && expr[nchr + 1] == '+' || chr == '-' && expr[nchr + 1] == '-') {
            INIT_VALS();    // Retrieves rval, lval, rlim, and llim
            if (fobst(expr, nchr, llim, rlim) & RIGHT)  // Operation cannot continue if another operator is in the way
                continue;
            CHK_VALS(RIGHT);    // Checks for overflow, getval() failure, and missing operand(s)
            result = chr == '+' ? rval + 1  // '++x' -> '+(x + 1)' 
                               : -rval - 1; // '--x' -> '-(-x + 1)'
            llim = nchr;    // Left limit of unary operation is operator position   
            INIT_EXPR();    // Retrieves new expression
            #ifdef DEBUG
                puts(expr);
            #endif
        }
    }
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {    // SQUARE ROOT/OTHER ROOT
        if (chr == '!') {
            INIT_VALS();
            if (expr[nchr + 1] == '!') {
                if (fobst(expr, nchr, llim, rlim) & (LEFT & RIGHT)) // Needs both sides of operator
                    continue;
                CHK_VALS(LEFT|RIGHT);
                if (rval < 0 && (int) lval % 2 == 0)
                    goto evenroot_err;
                if (lval == 0)
                    goto zeroroot_err;
                result = rval < 0 ? -pow(-rval, 1 / lval) : pow(rval, 1 / lval);    // Negative root workaround
            } else {
                if (fobst(expr, nchr, llim, rlim) & RIGHT)  // Needs only the right side of operator
                    continue;
                CHK_VALS(RIGHT);
                if (rval < 0)
                    goto evenroot_err;
                llim = nchr;
                result = sqrt(rval);
            }
            INIT_EXPR();
            #ifdef DEBUG
            puts(expr);
            #endif
        }
    }
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {    // EXPONENT
        if (chr == '^') {
            INIT_VALS();
            if (fobst(expr, nchr, llim, rlim) & (LEFT & RIGHT))
                continue;
            CHK_VALS(LEFT|RIGHT);
            result = pow(lval, rval);
            INIT_EXPR();
            #ifdef DEBUG
            puts(expr);
            #endif
        }
    }
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {    // MULTIPLICATION/DIVISION/REMAINDER
        if (chr == '*' || chr == '/' || chr == '%') {
            INIT_VALS();
            if (fobst(expr, nchr, llim, rlim) & (LEFT & RIGHT))
                continue;
            CHK_VALS(LEFT|RIGHT);
            if (rval == 0 && chr != '*')
                goto divzero_err;
            if (chr == '*')
                result = lval * rval;
            else if (chr == '/')
                result = lval / rval;
            else if (chr == '%') {
                if (isequal(lval, (int) lval) && isequal(rval, (int) rval))
                    result = (int) lval % (int) rval;
                else
                    goto modulus_err;
            }
            INIT_EXPR();
            #ifdef DEBUG
            puts(expr);
            #endif
        }
    }
    for (nchr = 0; (chr = expr[nchr]); nchr++) {    // ADDITION/SUBTRACTION/UNARY PLUS/UNARY MINUS
        if (chr == '+' || chr == '-') {
            if (chr == '+' && expr[nchr + 1] == '+' || chr == '-' && expr[nchr + 1] == '-') // Increment/Decrement found
                goto evaluate;
            INIT_VALS();
            if (fobst(expr, nchr, llim, rlim) & RIGHT)
                continue;
            CHK_VALS(RIGHT);
            if (llim == INT_FAIL)
                llim = nchr;
            result = chr == '+' ? lval + rval : lval - rval;
            INIT_EXPR();
            #ifdef DEBUG
            puts(expr);
            #endif
        }
    }

    reevaluate:
    while (strcspn(expr, OPERS + 2) != strlen(expr)) {
        if ((result_str = dtos(evaluate(expr), DBL_DIG)) == NULL)
            goto dtos_err;
        if ((result_str = dtos(evaluate(expr), DBL_DIG)) == STR_OVER)
            goto overflow_err;
        free(expr);
        expr = result_str;
    }

    if (isequal(result = stod(expr), DBL_OVER))
        goto overflow_err;
    free(expr);
    return result;

    opermiss_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Missing operand");    // Exits program if using command-line
        return DBL_FAIL;
    evenroot_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Even root of negative number");
        return DBL_FAIL;
    zeroroot_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Root cannot be zero");
        return DBL_FAIL;
    divzero_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Divide by zero");
        return DBL_FAIL;
    modulus_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Remainder takes integers only");
        return DBL_FAIL;
    getval_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Internal error (evaluate.getval)");
        return DBL_FAIL;
    dtos_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Internal error (evaluate.dtos)");
        return DBL_FAIL;
    overflow_err:
        free(expr);
        fail("Number too large");
        return DBL_FAIL;
}

double getval(char *_expr, size_t _operpos, char _dir) {    // Dynamic memory: val_str
    bool reading = false;
    char chr, *val_str = NULL;
    size_t val_low, val_high;   // Range of indices in which value is located
    int nchr;
    double num;

    if (_dir != 'l' && _dir != 'r') // Left and right directions only
        return DBL_FAIL;
    for (nchr = _dir == 'r' ? _operpos + 1 : _operpos - 1; (chr = _expr[nchr]) && nchr >= 0; _dir == 'r' ? nchr++ : nchr--) {   // Get size of value string
        if (isnumer(chr) && !reading) {
            reading = true;
            _dir == 'r' ? (val_low = nchr) : (val_high = nchr);
        } else if (!isnumer(chr) && reading) {
            _dir == 'r' ? (val_high = nchr) : (val_low = nchr);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!reading)   // No value found
        return 0;   // Must return 0 in this case to ensure proper evaluate() functionality (used in unary + and -)
    else if (nchr == -1)    // Reached beginning of expression
        val_low = 0;
    else if (chr == 0)  // Reached end of expression
        val_high = strlen(_expr) - 1;
    if ((val_str = popsub(_expr, val_low, val_high)) == NULL) {
        free(_expr);
        return DBL_FAIL;
    }
    if ((num = stod(val_str)) == DBL_FAIL) {
        free(val_str);
        return DBL_OVER;
    }
    free(val_str);
    return num; // Convert value string to value
}

double stod(const char *_s) {   // Equivalent to atof(), except that it does not print inaccurate numbers
    bool read_decim = false, is_negative = false, reading = false;
    char chr;
    int nchr;
    double num = 0, placeval = 0.1;

    for (nchr = 0; (chr = _s[nchr]) && nchr <= DBL_DIG + is_negative + read_decim; nchr++) {    // DBL_DIG is accurate digit limit
        if (chr == '-' && !is_negative && !reading)
            is_negative = true;
        else if (chr == '.' && !read_decim && !reading)
            read_decim = true;
        if (!read_decim && isdigit(chr)) {
            num *= 10;
            num += chr - 48;
        } else if (isdigit(chr)) {
            reading = true;
            num += placeval * (chr - 48);   // '0' = 48
            placeval /= 10;
        }
    }
    if (nchr > DBL_DIG && !read_decim)
        return DBL_OVER;
    if (is_negative)
        num *= -1;
    return num;
}
```

**eval.h**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef PARSE_H
#define PARSE_H

#ifdef __GNU_LIBRARY__
#include <err.h>
#define PROG_NAME\
    program_invocation_name[1] == '/' ?\
    program_invocation_name + 2 :\
    program_invocation_name             // Ignore './' if included 

extern char *program_invocation_name;
#else
#define PROG_NAME   "eval"
#endif /* #ifdef __GNU_LIBRARY__ */

/* Initializes left- and right-hand values in evaluate() */
#define INIT_VALS()\
    lval = getval(expr, nchr, 'l');\
    rval = getval(expr, nchr, 'r');\
    llim = getlim(expr, nchr, 'l');\
    rlim = getlim(expr, nchr, 'r')

/* Initializes new expression string in evaluate() */
#define INIT_EXPR()\
    if ((result_str = dtos(result, DBL_DIG)) == NULL) {\
        free(expr);\
        fail("Internal error (evaluate.dtos)");\
    }\
    if ((expr = pushsub(expr, result_str, llim, rlim)) == NULL) {\
        free(result_str);\
        fail("Internal error (evaluate.pushsub)");\
    }

/* Checks for overflow, getval() failure, and missing operand(s) in evaluate()
 * Requires needed values, LEFT or RIGHT */
#define CHK_VALS(reqval)\
    if (isequal(rval, DBL_OVER) || isequal(lval, DBL_OVER))\
        goto overflow_err;\
    if (isequal(rval, DBL_FAIL) || isequal(lval, DBL_FAIL))\
        goto getval_err;\
    if (reqval & RIGHT && rlim == INT_FAIL)\
        goto opermiss_err;\
    if (reqval & LEFT && llim == INT_FAIL)\
        goto opermiss_err

#define INT_FAIL    INT_MAX     // Passed by [type]-returning functions on failure
#define DBL_FAIL    DBL_MAX
#define DBL_OVER    FLT_EPSILON // Passed by [type]-returning functions on overflow
#define STR_OVER    "..."
#define CHK_PASS    -1          // Used by chk_parenth() and chk_syntax(); Indicates valid syntax
#define RIGHT       1
#define LEFT        2
// #define DEBUG                // If defined, prints debug info

extern bool CMD_LINE;
static const char *VAL_CHRS = "+-!^*/%.()\n1234567890'",
                  *OPERS = "+-!^*/%",
                  *DBLS = "+-!",    // Can be double
                  *UNRY = "+-!",    // Can be unary
                  *BNRY = "^*/%";   // Can only be binary

/* Prints error message and exits program */
extern void fail(const char *_desc);

/* Prints string with character at given position underlined */
extern void printu(const char *_s, size_t _hpos);

/* Returns string representation of double
 * Returns NULL on failure
 * Returns OVERFLOW on overflow
 * Resulting string must be freed */
extern char *dtos(double _x, size_t _sig);

/* Returns new, allocated substring spanning the given elements
 * Returns NULL on failure */
extern char *popsub(const char *_s, size_t _low, size_t _high);

/* Returns new, allocated string where substring replaces given elements in old string
 * Frees given string and substring while returning a newly allocated one
 * Returns NULL on failure */
extern char *pushsub(char *_s, char *_sub, size_t _low, size_t _high);

/* Evaluates mathemetical expression starting from given index position
 * Returns string representation of result depending on index
 * Returns NULL on failure */
extern char *simplify(const char *_expr, size_t _from);

/* Returns true if floating-point numbers are equal */
extern bool isequal(double _x, double _y);

/* Returns true if character is in string */
extern bool isin(const char _x, const char *_y);

/* Returns true if character is numerical (digit || '-' || '.') */
extern bool isnumer(char _c);

/* Determines whether a parenthesis indicates multiplication */
extern bool toast(const char *_expr, size_t _parpos);

/* Get digit at given place */
extern size_t getdigit(double _x, int _place);

/* Returns number of whole places */
extern size_t nplaces(double _x);

/* Returns index position of first invalid parenthesis of expression
 * Returns CHK_PASS if no invalid parentheses are found */
extern int chk_parenth(const char *_expr);

/* Returns index position of first invalid character of expression
 * Returns CHK_PASS if no invalid characters are found */
extern int chk_syntax(const char *_expr);

/* Returns left- or right-hand limit of range of operation at given position in expression
 * Returns INT_FAIL if invalid direction or operand is missing */
extern int getlim(char *_expr, size_t _operpos, char _dir);

/* Returns OBS_R or OBS_L depending on type of obstruction(s)
 * If none are found, returns 0
 * Returns INT_FAIL on failure */
extern size_t fobst(const char *_expr, size_t _operpos, size_t _llim, size_t _rlim);

/* Evaluates mathematical expression from index position 0
 * Ignores parentheses and syntax errors
 * Returns DBL_FAIL on failure */
extern double evaluate(const char *_expr);

/* Returns left- or right-hand value of the operand at given position in the expression
 * Returns DBL_FAIL on failure */
extern double getval(char *_expr, size_t _operpos, char _dir);

/* Returns double representation of string
 * Returns DBL_FAIL on overflow */
extern double stod(const char *_s);

#endif /* #ifndef PARSE_H */
```

GitHub: https://github.com/crypticcu/eval

Comment: Thanks for this great question - I hope you get some good reviews, and I hope to see more of your contributions here in future!

Answer (score 1):

## Naming

Please don't use ALL_CAPS identifiers for things that are not preprocessor macros:

> ```
> extern bool CMD_LINE;
> static const char *VAL_CHRS = "+-!^*/%.()\n1234567890'",
>                   *OPERS = "+-!^*/%",
>                   *DBLS = "+-!",    // Can be double
>                   *UNRY = "+-!",    // Can be unary
>                   *BNRY = "^*/%";   // Can only be binary
> ```

The usual naming convention helps alert us to names that don't obey the C rules of scope, and that expand arguments rather than evaluating them.  When we name other things this way, it introduces confusion.

```
extern bool command_line_flag;
static const char *const valid_chars = "+-!^*/%.()\n1234567890'";
static const char *const all_operators = "+-!^*/%";
static const char *const unary_operators = "+-!";    // Can be unary
static const char *const binary_operators = "^*/%";   // Can only be binary
```

## String conversion

> ```
> ndec = atoi(argv[2]);
> ```

Prefer `strtol()` or `sscanf()`, because `atoi()` has no way of reporting failure, and we need to distinguish that from actual entered zero.

## Terminal escapes

> ```
>     puts("\n\e[4mresult\e[24m");
> ```

Don't assume that your output is going to a terminal, or that a connected terminal understands the control codes you expect.  If you really want to do fancy terminal stuff, then (a) make it optional with a command-line flag and (b) use termcap or curses to abstract away the handling of different terminal types.

## Know your tools

> ```
>         swap = expr;    // Swap causes 'still reachable' error in valgrind
> ```

I like this - it shows that you've been using Valgrind to exercise your program.

Even better would be to unit-test as much as possible - occasionally run the tests under Valgrind, too.

Comment: Thank you for the review! Every practice you mentioned was helpful and to-the-point. Now I know to improve my program's handling of flags, so that I can implement your escape code suggestion along with some other features I had in mind.

Comment: If you like the review, the Stack Exchange way to show that is to vote the answer (the ▲ at top left of the answer).  You can also "accept" an answer when you feel your code is completely reviewed - don't do that just yet, because my review is fairly cursory and you may well get a better one if you wait.